# How to combine adjacent same elements of a list in python?

Tags: python

This is my list:

```
nab = ['b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```

I want to combine the same elements which are adjacent into another list, and if they are not the same, just return the element itself.
The output that I am looking for is:

```
['b', 'a', 'b', 'a']
```

I mean:
two `'b'` ---> `'b'`, one `'a'` ---> `'a'`, three `'b'` ---> `'b'`, four `'a'` ---> `'a'`
I want to know the length of the new list.

Comment: So, have you done anything yourself yet?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Also see Stack Overflow guidance on [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is unacceptable.

Comment: `itertools.groupby` creates subiterators for consecutive keys in a collection. You just need the first value of each of the subiterators. `[next(grp).upper() for _, grp in itertools.groupby(n)]`.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much @tdelaney, I did it as below:

```
import itertools  
nab = ['B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A']
U = []
key_func = lambda x: x[0]  
for key, group in itertools.groupby(nab, key_func): 
    U.append(list(group))
print(U)
print(len(U))

Output: 
[['B', 'B'], ['A'], ['B', 'B'], ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], ['B', 'B', 'B'], ['A', 'A'], ['B', 'B'], ['A', 'A'], ['B'], ['A'], ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], ['A']]
```